# Error Vagrant Provisioning with Virtual Box on Fedora

Tags: ansible, vagrant, virtualization

I'm Provisioning Vagrant Box with Virtual-box on Fedora 26.

```
$ vagrant -v
Vagrant 1.9.1
$ virtualbox -v
virtualbox 5.1
```

Below is the error;

```
muhammadtaqi@localhost etc]$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu/trusty64'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/home/muhammadtaqi/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20170918.0.1/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1506105327930_50139", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "6", "--disk", "/home/muhammadtaqi/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1506105327930_50139/box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /home/muhammadtaqi/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20170918.0.1/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the imported medium '/home/muhammadtaqi/VirtualBox VMs/ubuntu-cloudimg-trusty-vagrant-amd64_1506105327930_50139/box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: Compressed image is corrupted '/home/muhammadtaqi/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20170918.0.1/virtualbox/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component ApplianceWrap, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 886 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Comment: Did you download this vmdk, or did you create it yourself with virtualbox? Most of the guidance out there states that you have a corrupt vmdk. Others suggest maybe the VMDK was intended for different virtualization software.

Comment: I just installed vagrant, virtualbox, then `vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up` and got the above error.

Comment: So what's providing the vmdk file? Perhaps that is your issue - are you referencing a file that doesn't exist? Does `ls -alh /home/muhammadtaqi/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-VAGRANTSLASH-trusty64/20170918.0.1/virtualbox/box-disk1.vmdk` show the file?

Comment: `No such file or directory`

Comment: Based on that, it sounds like that's the issue: There is no image file for virtualbox to start up. You'll need to get or build one.

Comment: How, I do this before on Ubuntu it works well with just `vagrant init ubuntu/trusty64; vagrant up`, but now on fedora 26 gets error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to start with a clean sheet by removing the .vagrant.d folder or start to remove the corrupted zip. When the file or folder has been removed, one could run `vagrant up` again and check whether it works.